# OrientDB's OrientGraph.shutdown() causes exception everytime it is called

Tags: java, orientdb

I have noticed that OrientDB's shutdown() method (instance method of OrientGraph) is causing the following exception everytime it is called:

```
Method threw 'com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph.toString()
```

The exception is silent and there is no printout in the console or log. It is only seen while tracing during debugging.

I call it like the following:

```
transaction.commit();
transaction.shutdown(); // silent exception is seen here during tracing
```

And just for the record I get a OrientGraphFactory like this:

```
OrientGraphFactory gf = new OrientGraphFactory(dbLocation, "admin", "admin", true);
OrientGraph transaction = gf.getTx();
```

What is the cause of the exception?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Could you create issue in bug tracker we will investigate and fix it ?